# PHP CLI Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

Tags: php, linux, raspberry-pi

I am trying to run a PHP script from the CLI (command line interface) and get this error as if PHP curl is not loaded.

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function curl_init()

I have been looking and tried many solutions on here and no results.

**What I have done**

1. Updated PHP
2. Updated Linux system
3. Installed php-curl extension
4. Copied over Apache php.ini to cli/php.ini

**What does work**

1. Running curl_init from Apache (web request)
2. Running the command: php5 -q file.php (This works but I get another error regarding the class Thread not being loaded, but seems curl_init should be easier to fix)

[image: Inside php conf.d for CLI (All the same as Apache)]

Answer (score 1):

(php 7.4, ubuntu 20.04)

I was getting  "Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function" in an unfamiliar library.

I retested with a simple code snippet and got the same error.

```
<?php
    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt ($curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://www.php.net");
    curl_exec ($curl);
    curl_close ($curl);
?>
```

I installed php curl
`sudo apt-get install php-curl`
and retested.

That fixed the problem.